# rails: nested resources saving empty records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

I have created a simple form of nested resources. I can't get the child form todo_item to save correctly.  When I click the "create todo item" button, an empty record will be created and saved no matter what I put in the title field.

The code is really simple and the parent record is saving fine. the child records are displaying  so I can't figure out what could be wrong.  Please help.

My models:

```
class TodoItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :todo_list
end

class TodoList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todo_items, dependent: :destroy
end
```

My controllers:

```
class TodoItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_todo_list
  before_action :set_todo_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.new
  end

  def create
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.new

    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo_list.save
        format.html { redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @todo_list }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @todo_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def set_todo_item
      @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_todo_list
      @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:todo_list_id])
    end

    def todo_item_params
      params.require(:todo_item).permit(:title, :due_date, :description, :text, :completed)
    end

end
```

View.html.erb:

```
<h1>New Todo Item</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', @todo_list %>
```

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for([@todo_list, @todo_item]) do |f| %>
 ...

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the create method:

```
def create
@todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.create(todo_item_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @todo_list.save
    format.html { redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo item was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @todo_list }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @todo_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Comment: `.create` then `if @todo_list.save` doesn't make much sense, does it?

Comment: Thank you jvillian and Cryptex Technologies!  I do find Rails logic hard to follow.  Maybe just need to get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize the `@todo_item` here:

```
def create
  @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.new # <===== INITIALIZED HERE

  respond_to do |format|
    if @todo_list.save # <===== SAVED HERE WITHOUT EVER ASSIGNING VALUES.
      format.html { redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo item was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @todo_list }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @todo_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

But, don't provide any arguments to `new`. So, the new record has no values.

Instead, do something more like:

```
@todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.new(todo_item_params)
```

Perhaps you should also add some validations so you could avoid this situation.

Comment: I don't have a parameter added yet.  I am adding them on the UI.  I have just edited my original post to include the picture.  When I click on New Todo Item, a form appears and I enter the value there.  They are not supplied from the "new" method.

Comment: Take a look in the `create` action, not the `new` action.